# Remove minus-signs from list

Tags: map

I have a list that is of the following form

```
{-x,y,-z,a}
```

I want this set to become this:

```
{x,y,z,a}
```

I tried the following:

```
{-x,y,-z,a}/.{Minus->Plus}
```

But with no success. Functions like Abs also don't work, since x,y,z,a are not defined.

Comment: Try the rule `-1*x_ :> x`

Comment: Oh that works fine! Thank you!

Comment: `{-x, y, -z, a}  /. -t_ :> t` works too.

Comment: If you want to see what are the real "words" behind the expression `{-x,y,-z,a}` try : `FullForm[{-x,y,-z,a}]`, you will see there no `Minus`, so your replacement rule will have no effect.

Comment: I didn't know about the FullForm expression yet. Thank you for that, that may create lots less struggle in the future with similar problems :)

Comment: If you get the `Head` of first element: `list={-x,y,-z,a};
    Head[list[[1]]]`  you see that it is `Times` whereas the second element's head is `Symbol` so you can extract negative and positive elemtns separately and do whatever modification you need on them.  For example: `Join[-1*Cases[list,Except[_Symbol]],Cases[list,_Symbol]]`